# What can be the optimized or efficient way to transform/modify the received JSON input response keys in JavaScript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, rxjs, casting

**I have the solution for the problem** but I am posting this question in community in search of a Lightweight or say efficient way to do this if **possible**. Thus a better approach/advise is appreciated.

I have a **dictionary** / key Value pair data which looks like below basically its the mapping that will be used for transformation of the response.

---

```
    KEYS  :  VALUE
 

    "score": "RelevantScore",
    "headline": "Headline",
    "subtitle1": "PublishedDate",
    "subtitle2": "Stage",
    "body": "Summary",
    "labels": "Tag"
```

---

My aim is to transform the JSON Input response, I need to replace the old properties (VALUE) with its mapped KEY from the mapping data above. let take a example below

**I have a JSON object with the following content:**  **(ASSUME INPUT RESPONSE RECIVED)**

```
"Data": [{
            "RowId": 1,
            "Headline": "some data",
            "PublishedDate": "2022-09-29",
            "Summary": " some data",
            "SourceURL": "https://www.google.com",
            "RelevantScore": 0,
            "Stage": null,
            "Tag": "",          
}]
```

I want to change the "RelevantScore" key to "score" so it would become **(EXPECTED OUTPUT AFTER SWAPPING)**

```
"Data": [{
            "RowId": 1,
            "headline": "some random headline",
            "subtitle1": "2022-09-29",
            "body": "some data",
            "SourceURL": "https://www.google.com",
            "score": 0,
            "subtitle2": null,
            "labels": "",
}]
```

*Note :- We will be using the mapping table above to swap the keys*

**The Input JSON response properties name will be replaced/Swapped by the respective mapping key so that a new response can be crafted from the old one.** non matching keys can be ignored

Simple Example :-  **RelevantScore** key from response is being replaced by its mapped value **Score** to form a new response object.

**EXISTING FUNCTION I HAVE:-**

```
function renameKey ( obj, oldKey, newKey ) {
  obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
  delete obj[oldKey];
}
```

**EXISTING APPROACH:-**

```
const json = `
  [
    {
      "RelevantScore":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb"
    }
  ]
`;
```

```
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
arr.forEach( obj => renameKey( obj, 'RelevantScore', 'Score' ) ); // Call to the method
const updatedJson = JSON.stringify( arr );
```

**RESULT **:-

```
const json = `
  [
    {
      "Score":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb"
    }
  ]
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transformResposne(dynamicData :any[]): any [] {

      dynamicData.forEach( obj => renameKeys( obj, new Map(Object.entries(this.controls))));
      function renameKeys( obj, columnMap : Map<string, string> ) {
        columnMap.forEach(function(oldkey, newKey) {
          if (oldkey in obj)
          {
            obj[newKey] = obj[oldkey];
            delete obj[oldkey];
          }
        })
      }
      return dynamicData;
   
  };
```

**DATA RESPRESENTATION** :-

```
dynamicData = [{
           "RelevantScore": 0                
     }]

   controls = {
    "score": "RelevantScore",
   }
```

**OUTPUT :-**

```
 dynamicData = [{
               "score": 0                
         }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `replacer` parameter in [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(arr, function(key, value) {
  if (table.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    this[table[key]] = value; // add new key
    return; // don't add old key
  }
  /* uncomment the next line if you want to add not matching keys as well */
  // return value;
});
```

For simplicity I reversed keys and values in the matching table, but you should get the idea.

Comment: 0


The replacer function in JSON.stringify, does not allow you to replace keys, as documented in MDN. It allows you to transform values, or to omit key/value pairs altogether (by returning undefined).

Comment: @VihyatDixit you cannot directly replace keys, but you can add the new key/value while omitting the old one, and that would be technically a replacement.